# Xamarin Forms Entry opens only on double click (Android)

Tags: xamarin.forms

Currently I have a problem when I apply a style to an Entry it only opens on the second click. This only occurs when the applied Style uses the Visual State Manager with the VisualState Focused. If I remove the VisualState "Focused" the problem is solved.
Used style Code:

```
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Color_Text_OnWhite}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Color_Text_OnWhite_Disabled}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState Name="Focused">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Color_Text_OnWhite}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Color_Text_OnWhite}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
```

Here is the Video to show the problem: https://vimeo.com/588825086
Is there a workaround available?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the `FontAttributes`. Delete the code below would be okay.

```
<Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
```

The seetings of the Font like FontSize, FontAttributes with VisualState would make the Keyboard does not appear unless you tap twice.

The issue of FontSize is reported and has not solved yet. I would reported this FontAttributes as well. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4573